# How to get loginId of a logged user in SpringBoot application for change password feature implementation

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, jsp

I'm trying to implement a change password feature in my application. My application is developed in Springboot backend and client side is jQuery and jsp. I'm new to SpringBoot programming.

So what i want is, to change the password of a logged in user. Backend login handler is handled by spring security. So now once the user is logged in, i would like to implement the change password feature.
So below is the control flow, which i have implement to achieve password change feature for a logged in user.

**sucessfulLoginPage.jsp**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="changePassword"> Change Password  </a>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
$("#changePassword").click(function(){
        modifyPassword("user/changePassword/"+$("#loginUserId").val());
    });
    
});

function modifyPassword(suffix) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "/abc/"+suffix,
        success : function(data) {
            $(".inner-jsp").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
@GetMapping("/changePassword/{id}")
    public String changePassword(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findOne(id));
        return "/user/changePassword";
    }
```

**Modal User class**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long userId;
}
```

So once i have above things in place, what i need, is userId to create a get request of
`http://localhost:****/abc/user/changePassword/1` 
where 1 is the userId.

To get userID i need something like below in my **sucessfulLoginPage.jsp**

`<input type="hidden" id="loginUserId" value='${user.userId}'/>`

but i'm not sure how to get this userId in **sucessfulLoginPage.jsp**. I once thought of writing a logic, where i can get Principal user details in **Controller.java** and pass it to **sucessfulLoginPage.jsp**
like
 `model.addAttribute("user",principalUser.getId())`

But i'm not getting anything here. I would like to get an idea how to get userId in **controller.java** or directly in **sucessfulLoginPage.jsp** so that i can create a request of `http://localhost:****/abc/user/changePassword/1`.

Comment: maybe adding the `userID` in `session` would work .

Comment: @Swati thx swati, i just learned we cannot get getid values from js session attribute as those are available only in server side, so instead i passed the value to form through model.addAttribute and getting details from Principal user object from Spring security details.